# How to send content to server in background ? ios

Tags: ios, background, ios8, ios9

- First of all i need to describe what i am going to do: when user launch my application the app start collecting statistics about the user activities and behavior, once the the user close the app (app enter background) the application upload all statistics to server.
- the problem if the user presses home button twice and removes application from multitasking screen. then the application may not succeed to send statistics to server. because it will be terminated.

my solutions:

1. enable Background fetch , in background modes. but I don't think that will help because according to apple:  [the system does not relaunch apps after they are force quit by the user](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7)
2. using [Executing Finite-Length Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) , i  tried it , it won't send the data if user remove the app from multitasking screen.
3. using [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) to Downloading Content in the Background, but according to apple `If the user terminates your app, the system cancels any pending tasks`.

so all above solutions will not work if user terminate the application, any solution ?

I noticed that if i terminate the appstore app (remove it from multitasking screen ) while there is an application being downloaded , the application will continue downloading normally. is this just for appstore app ?

Answer (score 0):

If the user terminates an app, the app terminates. There is nothing you can do about this. iOS devices are meant to be *controllable by the user*.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you might add all the statistics to a queue on disk, and empty that queue only **after** the app has successfully uploaded the data to the server.

- If the user doesn't force-quit, this will work at once, in just the way you want.
- If the user does force-quit, the data will not be uploaded and the queue will still be present on disk. When the app is started, it can check the queue and upload it immediately.

You ought to be doing something like this in any case, to deal with cases like the user going underground for an hour, or taking a long-distance flight.

I suspect that the App Store app does not install apps, but tells a system process to install them.